# does Apple allow template style apps to pass review?

Tags: ios, mobile, app-store, hybrid

I have an app which will go to our clients and then they can have their clients install it. 
Meaning there would be multiple versions of the master app but with customization per client.  example 200 of our clients get the master app and then can customize it (text and images only via web) 
Will Apple allow something like this?

Is there another way to get around this distribution model?  I guess a good example of it would be a real estate agent having an app that's customized and on the app store but it's still Brand XYZ's app.

thanks in advance

Comment: The alternative would be Enterprise Distribution (by each of your clients), I guess.

Comment: You may want to have a look at Enterprise licensing. Is the app something that your clients would use, or their customers? If the clients direct then you probably want Enterprise. If their customers, then you'll probably want to submit separate skinned apps for each client.

Comment: yes it would be their customers. A separate skinned app is what I was thinking but then Apple begin rejecting them if they are similar.  That's what I was under the impression of anyway.  But another possibility I thought was maybe a token/code system to unlock the master app where their clients would get a unique code tying them to our client.And then the app would be built dynamic based off the code.  Might not  be as easy as that though.